# Custom to specifically have whiskey after fish because of danger

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, fish, liquor-beer

The Rema ([YD 116:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.116.3)) says to eat something and drink something between having fish and meat.

Many have the custom to specifically make a *lechaim* between fish and meat, meaning they have something alcoholic, like whiskey.

Tosafos ([Moed Kattan 11a](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Moed_Katan.11a.19.1), brought by Rabbi Akiva Eiger to [YD 116:5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa/yd_x4370.pdf#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&view=FitH)) say it's dangerous to drink **water** after fish. Someone told me this is the source for the custom that some who fulfill the Rema specifically have whiskey instead of water. I was wondering if this explanation is brought anywhere.

Comment: Another way to get in another shot

Comment: I heard a story about someone who was so scrupulous about separating between fish and meat at his Yom Tov meal that he would smoke a cigar in between courses. Interesting set of priorities there: stringent to excess about separating between fish and meat, unbelievably lenient about smoking on Yom Tov.

Comment: Seems to be the driving force here (Belzer Shabbos Newsletter): https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjqgdC_l8njAhXmlOAKHd-RA8QQFjAEegQIBBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbeinenu.com%2Fsystem%2Ffiles%2Falonim%2F134_38_77.pdf%3Fdownload%3D1&usg=AOvVaw3Xo3p6etCnmJJooD22sSXH

Comment: One scientific fact is that alcohol kills bacteria. (I'm not a doctor, though I sometimes play one on this site ;-) Perhaps, this is one, if not the main, reason why they recommended whiskey or something with a high alcohol content. Though, I would imagine that beer would suffice, and, I think it tastes better.

Comment: I'm surprised that Mo'ed Kattan mentions that drinking water is dangerous. Are they afraid that the fish would swim in your esophagus or intestines?

Comment: @Fred *Sakanta chamira me'issura* - but pretty ironic to smoke a cigar to avoid the ancient alleged danger of combining meat and fish.

Comment: http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-257791.html mentions wine but with no citation to a source.

Comment: @Loewian I have no idea how a cigar was supposed to accomplish anything, but he managed just fine without it on Shabbos.

Comment: @DanF the gemarra says **to** drink water after fish. Tosafos say it's dangerous

Comment: @Fred It seems you missed the whole point. The person had the cigar so that he can have smoked fish!

Answer (score 3):

Sh'arim M'tzuyanim B'Halacha [on Kitzur Shukchan Aruch] 33/2 makes this suggestion.